# Navigation(posh/pop) inside ViewControler exist in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

in my app i have UIScrollView that contains N ViewControllers that can be swiped to the left or right

In each controller i want to be able to push new viewController and  i managed to do that
im getting back to the original ViewController by executing 
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

the issue is when i execute this code the K+1(k original controller) viewController get Showed and then it pushed back to the wanted view controller

the project code can be downloaded from the link

[link to the project zip](http://moblix.co.il/TestCusomNavogationSweap.zip)

please advice how i can make the pop smooth without showing controller K+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I solved your problem: you have to enable in Interface Builder the Clip Subviews flag (right side in IB) on the View object (left side of IB) in that xib which contains the scrollview (in your example this is the TSFirstViewController.xib).

For more clarity here is a screenshot what have to be set:

[image]